# Use tmux attach with xargs

Tags: tmux, xargs

I'd like to create an alias that lets me browse all of my tmux windows with FZF and then attach that single window. What I have so far:

```
tmux list-windows -t main -F '#{session_name}:#{window_name}' | fzf | xargs "tmux attach -t"

# In FZF, I select a window named "main:mail".
```

This results in an error:

```
open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

When I add an `echo`, the outputted command looks fine though:

````
tmux list-windows -t main -F '#{session_name}:#{window_name}' | fzf | xargs echo tmux attach -t```

=> tmux attach -t main:mail
````

If I run `tmux attach -t main:mail` directly, it works fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

A simpler breakdown without fzf (that produces the same error) would be:

`echo "main:mail" | xargs tmux attach -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmux` needs stdin to be the terminal, but using a pipe will make stdin connect to the pipe output instead. Another possible solution for you is

```
tmux attach -t "$(tmux list-windows -t main -F '#{session_name}:#{window_name}' | fzf)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a workaround, but I'd appreciate knowing why the above didn't work and to have a better solutino:

```
run-shell tmux list-windows -t main -F "#{session_name}:#{window_name}" | fzf > /tmp/tmux-session && tmux attach -t $(cat /tmp/tmux-session)
```